# regarding distinct values in sql query

Tags: php, sql, distinct

I think its kind of easy but still all I tried didn't give the expected result.

When I try running this query: (on a larger table)

```
SELECT Id, Code, newCode, Course, Internship 
FROM courses
WHERE Year ='c' AND (Internship ='IS' OR Internship =  '')
ORDER BY newCode ASC
```

I get this result:

```
id  code    newCode  course
----------------------------
1   30002   3000231  aaaa-1
2   30002   3000232  aaaa-2
3   30002   300021   aaaa-a1
4   30002   300022   aaaa-a2
5   30009   300093   bbbb-1
6   30009   300093   bbbb-2
7   30012   3001231  cccc-1
8   30012   3001232  cccc-2
9   30012   300121   cccc-a1
10  30012   300122   cccc-a2
11  30012   300123   cccc-a3
12  30013   3001331  dddd-1
```

Let's say I want some kind of sql query that will give me the table of only the names of the courses, (every new course is a new value in the column- Code) , 
what I want to get  for example: (the first of every course is good)

```
id  code    newCode  course
----------------------------
1   30002   3000231  aaaa-1
5   30009   300093   bbbb-1
7   30012   3001231  cccc-1
12  30013   3001331  dddd-1
```

How do I do that?
I tried:

```
SELECT Id, Distinct Code, newCode, Course, Internship 
FROM courses
WHERE Year ='c' AND (Internship ='IS' OR Internship =  '')
ORDER BY newCode ASC
```

Why is it not working, without the "distinct" it works, with it, it fails.

Also, this next question is less important but still.. is there a way for me to get only the name of the course itself like: "aaaa" and not "aaaa-a1" considering the name doesn't have to be the same pattern like here, but i do know what are the possibilities of after the "- "  (like " -a1"  or " -a2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT Id, Code, newCode, Course, Internship 
FROM courses
WHERE Year ='c' AND (Internship ='IS' OR Internship =  '')
GROUP BY Code ORDER BY newCode ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `distinct` after the `select`, like this:

```
SELECT distinct Id, Code, newCode, Course, Internship 
FROM courses
WHERE Year ='c' AND (Internship ='IS' OR Internship =  '')
ORDER BY newCode ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

use distinct with first column, you cannot use distinct after first first column